# DataBase project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I have two database projects in Visual Studio which is purpose to deploy databases separately. First database project deploy DBFirst and second database project deploy DBSecond. DBFirst database is created successfully but I am struggling with second.

DBSecond contains stored procedures and views. Some of them referenced to DBFirst and DB project failed during the build process. Example I have following view in DBSecond:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DBFirst_CLM_Details]
AS
  SELECT          *
   FROM         [DBFirst].[dbo].[CLM_Details]
GO
```

That project failed during the build because it cannot resolve reference DBFirst. If I change "Build Action" property from Build to None project will build but it will skip that file.

How can I deploy that view and similar objects which have references to another database? I am using VS 2013 and target platform is MS Azure SQL Database

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can reference the first project in your second project or include both of them together since #2 is so tighlty coupled to #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-database references are not supported by Azure SQL Database. If you need it you should [go and vote for it](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/402636-cross-database-reference) to help prioritise its delivery. If you need the capability today you will need to invest time in querying and combining the data elsewhere in your application outside of Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Simon thanks for respond. I voted. But do you know (or somebody else) is it possible to use Cross-DB references in Database project in Visual Studio in any other Database types?

Comment: Recommend posting a new question on SO for that (or see if someone else has already answered).